# Why parameterized constructor can't be called while creating array of class Objects?

Tags: c++, default-constructor, construct

I am new to C++, I need some clarification about the constructor and my question here is:

1. Can we use a parameterized constructor while creating an array of class objects?
2. Or is it only possible to use a default constructor when creating an array of class objects?

Please explain how it can be done, or why it can't. I need a deeper understanding about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a parameterized constructor to initialize an array. See the following example.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int _a, bool _b) : a{_a}, b{_b} {}
private:
    int a;
    bool b;
};

int main() {
    Foo things[] = {{5, true},
                    {3, false},
                    {7, true}};
    return 0;
}
```

The array `things` is of `Foo` objects. I am using uniform initialization to construct 3 `Foo` objects in the array. These are relying on the parameterized constructor that I defined in the class.

Comment: Same way can we create multi dimensional array object?

Comment: @Nagarajan Yes, you would just have one more nested level of `{ }`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, although in C++03 there are some restrictions. This is valid:

```
A a[3] = { x, y, z };
```

But to call constructors taking multiple arguments you need to do something like:

```
A a[3] = { A(x1, x2, x3), A(y1, y2, y3), A(z1, z2, z3) };
```

In C++11 it is easier thanks to the new uniform initialization syntax:

```
A a[3] = { {x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}, {z1, z2, z3} };
```

Comment: First and second syntax requires copy constructor, so make sure the object is copyable and copy constructor is properly implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say we have this class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int i, const std::string& s);
    // ...
};
```

Then

1. Yes:

   ```
   std::vector<Foo> myFooVector(5, Foo(1, "bar"));
   ```

   The above creates a [*vector*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of five `Foo` objects, each having the arguments `1` and `"bar"` sent to the parameterized constructor.

   You can also use an array like e.g.

   ```
   std::array<Foo, 2> myFooArray = {
       { 1, "bar" },
       { 2, "quug" }
   };
   ```

   The above creates an [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) containing two `Foo` objects, each constructed using the parameterized constructor.
2. If you don't explicitly call any constructor, then the default constructor will be used. Using the examples from above:

   ```
   std::vector<Foo> myFooVector(5);
   ```

   This creates a vector containing five default-constructed `Foo` objects.

   And

   ```
   std::array<Foo, 2> myFooArray;
   ```

   This creates an array of two default-constructed `Foo` objects.

Comment: Extra brownie points if you mention benefits of `Foo` having a move constructor.